# Infinite Loop to JS driven text zoom animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have this code on a page which zooms in, zooms out and then restores the original text size.

I want to know how to **slow down** and **endlessly loop** this animation.

Below is the javascript -

```
$(".text1 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1.2", "-ms-zoom": "1.2", "top":"-5px"}, function(){
                $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "0.8", "-ms-zoom": "0.8", "top":"5px"}, function(){
                $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1", "-ms-zoom": "1", "top":""});                                                                       
                });                                                           
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: @JaromandaX not a solution, can I not make changes to this to execute what I want?

Comment: Actually, it is a solution. yes, you can alter your code to do what you want. The answer is in the code you posted already, the callback in the animate function is key

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX, if you don't mind, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: you want to loop all three parts of the animation, or just the last two parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add duration property to animate to slow it down. Call the animation recursively to make infinite loop like this:

```
function loop(){
    $(".text1 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1.2", "-ms-zoom": "1.2", "top":"-5px", duration: 1000}, function(){
        $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "0.8", "-ms-zoom": "0.8", "top":"5px", duration: 1000}, function(){
            $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1", "-ms-zoom": "1", "top":"", duration: 1000}, loop);                                                                       
        });                                                           
    });                                                               
}
loop();
```

Notice loop is declared and called twice, at the first is the trigger and second is for the next iteration of animation when zoom to 1 is done

Comment: Worked amazingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function anim1() {
    $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "0.8", "-ms-zoom": "0.8", "top":"5px"}, 2000, anim2);
}
function anim2() {
    $(".slide5 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1", "-ms-zoom": "1", "top":""}, 2000, anim1);
}

$(".text1 h1 span").animate({"zoom": "1.2", "-ms-zoom": "1.2", "top":"-5px"}, 1000, anim1);
```

The number (1000 or 2000 in the example) is how long the animation will take - bigger numbers will slow it down

this code will do the first part in a second, then the second and third continuously every 4 seconds